# What windows api functions exist to list file handles associated with a process id(PID)

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to write some code to list out any file handles with an associated process. I understand tools like handle and processexplorer exist. But these dont work for the implementation of the code im writing since it needs to be internal to the code. Sadly i cant seem to find what api calls procexe uses to find the file handles associated with that PID. Any one know good sources i can check out to figure this out?

Comment: need use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemExtendedHandleInformation`

Comment: awesome thank you. this is exactly what i was looking for. For anyone else interested there is a link to the undocumented windows structurs i found once @Michael gave me the above information. [link](http://www.exploit-monday.com/2013/06/undocumented-ntquerysysteminformation.html)

Comment: Okay but it's @RbMm that gave you the info, not me :)